# How to get name of ANY User from his ID in apex without SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, salesforce-id

I have an ID of user(say 00536000002qYTUIU8), which is not necessarily current context user,  and want to get that user's name in apex. I can do following to get this:

```
select name from User where id ='00536000002qYTUIU8'
```

But is there any way to avoid querying DB and get the name from any method, something like:

```
User.getUsername(ID)
```

Comment: If the user trigger the apexcode, `UserInfo.getUserName` ( don't remember the exact function from UserInfo) will return his name. Else I think it's the only way

Comment: @SimonPlacentino UserInfo class is for the current user only.

Comment: @SimonPlacentino : Yes, I want it for any random user.

Comment: You have to query, otherwise, no ready made API is available

Comment: I suppose you could create a custom setting with the user id as the key... Using that table would not count as a SOQL but would come with maintenance...

Comment: Why don't you want to use SOQL?

Comment: @Rangya You are right, that is why I specified "If the user trigger the apexcode".

You could do your own class to hide the SOQL query.
Create a `UserUtility` class with a static method `getUserName()` to do so

Comment: @Saroj Bear : To try and avoid 100 SOQL limit in case it may be hit if there are many SOQls in a transaction.

Comment: Can you let us know the exact requirement what are trying to do, is this going to be in a for loop? Because the only way is to do `SOQL Query`.

Comment: @RCS : Its not in a for loop. Yes I guess SOQL is fine for now , but if the problem arises then I can go with approach suggested by Girbot OR Daniel Ballinger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to reduce the SOQL call count for data you need frequently is to use the [Platform Cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_cache_namespace_overview.htm).

You could store the User ID to name lookup in the cache, and would then only need to do a SOQL query if the cache missed.

How effective this is will depend on how many User records you are dealing with and how much storage space you can allocate to the Cache.

---

You could also do an API call to get the data. Either to the REST API or the SOAP API. This would technically save you the SOQL query, but would use a callout instead. The other big downside of this approach is the performance. A callout will always be much slower than a direct SOQL query.

Comment: You need to register your organisation as "Remote Site" in Setup -> Security -> Remote Site Settings.

With your current SessionId:
`Http http    = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

String instance  = Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
String endPoint  = instance + '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/User/0050Y000000pmuYQAQ?fields=Name';
String sessionId  = 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId();
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setHeader('Authorization', sessionId);
request.setEndpoint(endPoint);
http.send(request).getBody();`